# Are changes made to a global variable, inside a function, reflected globally? Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables, local-variables

If I have a global variable, and I change the variable's value inside a function, will the change be reflected outside of the function?

e.g.

```
var blaah="blaah";

function myFunction(){
 blaah="blaah blaah";
}

console.log(blaah);
```

Will the output of `console.log();` be "blaah", or "blaah blaah".

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? You can even run code here in StackOverflow.

Comment: It seems to work, this question is more if there are exceptions, or if this is not cross-browser.

Comment: The output would be `blaah`, because you didn't run the function but you have conflicting variable names. If you want to know more I'd suggest you read the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: @elclanrs good catch, I'll fix that

Comment: The question is whether it can be ***EDITED***, not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the global variable that you defined would be changed (or edited) when you execute `myFunction();`. The answer to your question regarding the output of `console.log();` would be "blahh" though, because your function was not run yet.

For more support on variable scope, check out [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Hope that helps!

Liam